# Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' with Looker

Tags: iframe, single-sign-on, looker

I'm trying to display a iFrame with Looker SSO, I used [looker_sso_tool](https://fabio-looker.github.io/looker_sso_tool/) to generate the Embed URL, and it shows the dashboard I want, however when I try to use the url with a *localhost* application it shows the error:

> Refused to display 'https://xerpabr.looker.com/login' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I also notice the requested URL from this tool has a *Location Response* of:

> https://xerpabr.looker.com/embed/dashboards/2

While in localhost it is:

> https://xerpabr.looker.com/login

I'm using the [node_example](https://github.com/looker/looker_embed_sso_examples/blob/master/node_example.js) of sso embed, just changing the return to display the iFrame, like so:

```
res.end("<iframe height=400 width=600 src=" + url + "> </iframe> ");
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try generating a URL from the tester tool (with preview turned off) and serving that exact URL from localhost? I suspect the problem may be with something in your script, even though you said you didn't change much.

That error is often a bit of a red herring that means your URL isn't authenticating properly— Looker sets x-frame-option headers on the login page that prevent it from being embedded, so if the generated URL doesn't work to log you in and instead redirects to /login, the error can appear. If you take a generated URL from your script and pass it through the Admin > Embed url verification tool, do you get any hints?

You could also try asking over on [discourse.looker.com](https://discourse.looker.com) where there's a wealth of Looker experts!

Comment: Thank you! I could solve my problem by exploring the script, I'm not sure about what solve, but it's working now.